# PHP file upload - PNG without transparency still saves all black

Tags: php

I am writing a simple upload script that can upload an image a user specifies from their computer to my server.  It's extremely simple right now, but I want to account for `pngs` and `jpg/jpegs`.  JPGs save just fine, but pngs, whether they have transparency or not save as a totally black image.  I'm unsure why this is happening, but I have a feeling it has something to do with the `imagecreatetruecolor`?

```
  if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
  }
  else {
    $path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($path == 'png') {
      $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
      imagealphablending($src, true); // setting alpha blending on
      imagesavealpha($src, true); // save alphablending setting (important)
      header('Content-Type: image/png');
    } else {
      $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    }


    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadedfile);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if (800/800 > $r) {
      $newwidth = 800*$r;
      $newheight = 800;
    } else {
      $newheight = 800/$r;
      $newwidth = 800;
    }

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

    $filename = '../items/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    if ($path == 'png') {
      imagepng($tmp, $filename);
    } else {
      imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 80);
    }

    imagedestroy($tmp);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok found my issue, my condition was asking for `$path == 'png'` where the `$path` was the entire image name.  What I needed was `$ext == 'png'`.  Thanks to @wiseone for making me look at that again.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving a png image as jpg, check your
if($path == 'png') condition

Comment: The first condition or the second?  Because they are both focused on png as far as I can tell.  The first `== 'png'` sets up an image with transparency and does `imagecreatefrompng`, while the second condition does `imagepng()`

Comment: First condition, think it shld b $ext == png, $path returns your uploaded filename

Comment: What line? the src is `imagecreatefrompng` and the header is `Content-Type: image/png`